# How to verify the data stored in azure

Tags: database, unit-testing, manual-testing

We're in the designing phase. We are extracting the date using API calls and storing the extracted data in Azure SQL Server and i wanted to test whether the exact data is loading in azure or not.

Answer (score 0):

**To verify that the data has uploaded into Azure, take the following steps:**

```
Go to the storage account associated with your disk order.

Go to Blob service > Browse blobs. The list of containers is presented. Corresponding to the sub folder that you created under Block Blob and Page Blob`enter code here` folders, containers with the same name are created in your storage account. If the folder names do not conform to Azure naming conventions, then the data upload to Azure will fail.

To verify that the entire data set has loaded, use Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer. Attach the storage account corresponding to the Data Box Disk order and then look at the list of blob containers. Select a container, click …More and then click Folder statistics. In the Activities pane, the statistics for that folder including the number of blobs and the total blob size is displayed. The total blob size in bytes should match the size of the data set.
```